# how can I make gdb ignore .gdbinit

Tags: gdb, gdbinit

I have set up my ~/.gdbinit with some commands for a specific configuration.

Sometimes I would like to start gdb to ignore the .gdbinit.

Is there a mechanism to ignore .gdbinit or override it by another .gdbinit?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Run GDB with

```
gdb -nx
```

This skips the `.gdbinit` file processing.

Answer (score 2):

According to [GDB docs, Initialization Files](https://www.sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Initialization-Files.html#Initialization-Files) You want to skip your "Home directory early initialization files", to do so start GDB with `-nh`.

The accepted answer `-nx` also disables the "System wide initialization files" and the "Local directory initialization file".